Efficiency of Coaxial Rotors vs Single Rotors (and Contrarotating Propellers)
Why are coaxial rotors (or contra-rotating propellers) used given that there is such a high power efficiency penalty?
According to data I see in Principles of Helicopter Aerodynamics by Leishman,it seems that coaxial rotors have lower figures of merit than single rotors. According to the theory it can take up to 28% more power for a coaxial rotor to provide the same thrust as a single rotor in hover. The book also shows that even partial overlaps are less efficient than single rotors.
However it seems like there is this perception that coaxial (or overlapped rotors) are more efficient than single rotors. Some helicopters (Kamov series, K-Max), several multicopters and eVTOLs use coaxial/overlapping rotors. What gives? It seems like an excessive power penalty (+28%!) to take given in theory most designers are attempting to minimize power consumption for a given performance setting.
I was trying to understand this, and the only explanations I could devise were:

In theory the Figure of Merit of a Single Rotor doesn't consider the power to provide anti-torque. This is quoted as being 10-30% depending on where you read.

Some geometric or other constraint in the design forces the use of coaxial rotors. EX: desire to have no tail rotor incidents, or need to limit rotor diameter or tip speed.


Similarly, I notice the same trend on contra-rotating propellers. But I find the data I have is not very trusted (random online papers). Does anyone have good references to compare efficiencies of single propellers vs contra-rotating propellers?
Thank you!
Added reference picture! 

The premise of your question is not correct. Presumably 28% is the difference between rotors performance only, at equal disk loading (it's lower for coaxials), and without accounting for the tail rotor, which is a pure waste of power.
This has been researched:

The analysis of hover, forward flight, and steady level turns shows
the benefit of the coaxial rotor to lie in its reduced consumption of
induced power compared to the equivalent conventional rotor.
...
Simulations of a wind-up turn at constant advance ratio again show
the coaxial rotor to possess a distinct advantage over the conventional
system — a reduction in power of about 8% for load factors between 1.0
and 1.7 is observed at an advance ratio of 0.12 and a level flight thrust
coefficient of 0.0048.

Also, on a practical level, one can compare the Mi-28 with the Ka-50:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mil_Mi-28
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kamov_Ka-50#Specifications_(Ka-50)
They use the same powerplant and are similar in size, weight, and fuel capacity.
Despite its 14.5 m vs 17.2 m rotor diameter, the Ka-50 has a longer range, confirming the theoretical results - coaxial rotor helicopters are more power- and fuel-efficient.

Comparing the ranges of the Mi-28 vs. the Ka-50 is unfair since they have two very different powerplants and, most probably, fuel capacity...

@sophit They have a similar fuel capacity of ~2000L for either, and they use the same Klimov VK-2500 powerplant.

Yes but according to Wikipedia one is rated at 2400shp and the other at 2200shp. Plus they have different fuselage and shape i.e. different drag... a comparison is simply unfair. To do a comparison you should have exactly the same helicopter, one with coaxial rotors and one with conventional rotors or at least a bunch of machines to be able to make some sort of extrapolation

@sophit Or, better, remove the whole helicopter and work only with the rotors - as has been done in the research paper in my first link. The comparison is only to confirm that a real coaxial exists that isn't worse on fuel efficiency than a conventional.

Thank you for sharing that report! Took me a few days to read it but I think I understand. I suspect you're right that the graph from Leishman only shows the rotor effects and does not consider things like power consumption for tail rotor operation, or rotating wake vs airframe effects.

I suspect that you are not looking at the Leishman data in an entirely consistent way.  For example, you may need to compare the contra-rotating rotor to a single-rotating rotor with 2x the disk loading.  Can you cite the exact figure/page you are looking at?
Theory says that contra-rotating coaxial props / rotors should be able to be designed to be more efficient than single-rotation counterparts of equivalent disk loading (considering total thrust and total diameter).
This improvement is mostly based on designing the second rotor to turn the swirl component of velocity induced by the first rotor back 'straight' -- leading to a combined system with no swirl velocity.  The kinetic energy normally lost in the swirl component is now recovered in the axial component.
Gas turbines are designed in a similar way with rotor/stator pairs.
Many eVTOL concepts using counter-rotating rotors are doing so for a variety of reasons -- they want to keep the simplicity of a quad-rotor configuration, but they want to get redundancy of totally separate motor/drive/rotor systems at each post.  This also allows them to use smaller components (motors and drives) compared to a true quad-rotor system (for the same gross weight and diameters).  This may be beneficial when considering what components are available off the shelf.

Hi Rob! Thanks for your answer! I added the picture of Figure 2.30 that gave me the inspiration for this question!

How would I compare a single rotor to a coaxial rotor correctly using the the chart?

note that the swirl can help prevent the recirculation bubble from starting when descending at low forward speed.

I've gone through and read that section of Leishman.  It is a bit confusing exactly how he is comparing in each situation -- and how you would use this chart.  However, he stands clear that the coaxial is less efficient in the low disk loading situations usually used for rotorcraft.  He does draw explicit contrast to high disk loading propellers where we usually learn that counter rotating props are usually more efficient.
